# Permanently hide the debug area in an Xcode playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

Is it possible to to permanently disable the debug area in an Xcode playground? I know you can hide the debugger in the playground, but anytime an error occurs, which is common using a playground, it pops back up again. I am trying to work with a playground and a PDF simultaneously (split screen not available for Xcode) so my playground is small and the debugger area keeps getting in the way as I type. If it is possible how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

In Xcode 8.0:

Preferences -> Behaviors -> Playgrounds -> Generates Output

Then where it says "[Show] debugger with [Current Views]" where [] indicates drop down controls, change [Show] to [Hide].